# Class, What's the best way to use methods?

Tags: c#, oop, class, methods

I'm new to programming, learning myself, and yesterday i was developing a class to work with files using C# and i got a doubt... What's the best way to use the methods when you got a checkmethod and a createmethod?

yeah, i know, i wasn't clear here, so here's an exemple;

**Files.cs(Class)**

```
namespace Working_with_Files
{
  class Files
  {

    public bool CheckFile(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool CreateFile(string path)
    {
        if (CheckFile(path))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(path);
            return true;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

What's the best and fastest way to use this class methods? becouse when i use the CreateFile method, i've to check if there's a file with the same name already.

Best way is reference another method inside this method? like this;

```
namespace Working_with_Files
{
  class Files
  {

    public bool CheckFile(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool CreateFile(string path)
    {
        if (CheckFile(path))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(path);
            return true;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Best way is with the native File.Exists inside the CreateFile method? like this;

```
namespace Working_with_Files
{
  class Files
  {

    public bool CheckFile(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool CreateFile(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(path);
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, the best and fastest way is using CheckFile method on the Main Program before using the CreateFile method?

That's my doubt, sorry if i can't make it clear.

Comment: you have a reason to wrap CheckFile, don't you?

Comment: Well firstly, looks like they should be static methods - i see no ctor or instance variables...

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I do the following way:

If the "checking" code is more than one line of code then I move it to its own method.

You can also do:

```
return File.Exists(path);
```

inside the CheckFile method.

But regarding the performance/speed, don't worry. Write as many methods as needed, the speed difference is so little.

Readability of code matters more than tiny performance in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do premature optimalisations! First one is 'more clear', it's a subjective question.

And please rename the functions: if a function is called CheckFile, it should 'check' the file, content or something. Not check if the file exists --> rename to FileExists

Answer (score 1):

If you want fastest way, then I think you could use only your CreateFile method in first case. Because it uses ready to use frameworks File.Exists and File.Create methods. And as most developers do - if the framework or language provides the ready-to-use functions, then use them otherwise if that do not satisfy then combine those that exist at maximum.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your methods need extra functionality and you're not gilding the lily...

I think you're asking whether to duplicate functionality of one method within another, to which the answer is no.

"Using CheckFile method on the Main Program before using the CreateFile method" allows you to extend your CheckFile method without making it diverge in functionality from CreateFile, which is better encapsulation. (Alternatively make CreateFile call CheckFile if it will always need to do so)

Answer (score 1):

No need to create instance of the Files class, so either make all methods static as already suggested, or use such code pattern which in my opinion is more elegant:

```
namespace Working_with_Files
{
    public class Files
    {
        private static Files instance;
        public static Files Instance { get { return instance; } }

        static Files()
        {
            instance = new Files();
        }

        private Files()
        {
        }

        public bool CheckFile(string path)
        ......no change in rest of code.....
    }
}
```

And to call the methods:

```
Files.Instance.CheckFile("myfilehere")
```

Comment: This is more a comment then an answer because it is not related to the question. More a general tip.